# Problem while making an inserting sort program for arranging numbers in descending order

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, insertion-sort

I was trying to solve a C problem for arranging numbers in descending order using insertion sort. My program seems to work fine except for one problem, i.e. my program is taking `n+1` inputs when I am defining the size as `n`. However, The program then uses only the first `n` inputs and sorts them accordingly. Then, how do I stop the program from accepting one extra input? Please help.
The code is attached below.

```
//insertion sort in descending order
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    void printArray(int a[], int n);
    int size, i, j, ul, t;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int array[size];
    printf("Enter the array elements: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d \t", &array[i]);
    printf("\nThe original array is: \n");
    printArray(array, size);
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        ul = i;
        while (ul > 0)
        {
            if (array[ul] > array[ul - 1])
            {
                t = array[ul];
                array[ul] = array[ul - 1];
                array[ul - 1] = t;
            }
            ul -= 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe new array after sorting in descending order using Insertion Sort is: \n");
    printArray(array, size);
}

void printArray(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d \t", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Does that compile?

Comment: compiles and works for me.  I don't see the behavior you describe

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `scanf("%d \t", &array[i]);` reads characters from `stdin` and attempts to convert them to an `int`, then it reads any subsequent white space characters.  Hence it will not stop after `n` numbers because it needs to read at least one byte different from space, TAB, newline or other whitespace characters.

Just change the format string to `scanf("%d", &array[i]);`

Note also these remarks:

- you should check for invalid input to avoid undefined behavior.
- the return type of the `main` function is `int`
- the prototype `void printArray(int a[], int n);` should be at the global scope.

Here is a modified version:

```
//insertion sort in descending order
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(const int a[], int n);

int main(void) {
    int size;

    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size <= 0)
        return 1;

    int array[size];

    printf("Enter the array elements:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("\nThe original array is:\n");
    printArray(array, size);
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (array[j] > array[j - 1]) {
                int t = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe new array after sorting in descending order using Insertion Sort is:\n");
    printArray(array, size);
    return 0;
}

void printArray(const int a[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```